# Definition of automorphism functor for $\mathbf{Lie}(\mathbf{Aut})(R) = \mathrm{Der}(R).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

$\newcommand\Lie{\mathbf{Lie}} \newcommand\Aut{\mathbf{Aut}} \newcommand\Alg{\mathrm{Alg}} \newcommand\Grp{\mathrm{Grp}} \newcommand\Der{\mathrm{Der}}$

Let $F: \Alg \to \Grp$ be a functor and $R$ an algebra. Then $\Lie(F)(R)$ is a Lie algebra. My goal is to show that $\Lie(\Aut)(R)$ equals the Lie algebra of derivations $\Der(R).$

However, I am not sure how to define the functor $\Aut : \Alg \to \Grp.$ I can see two options:

1. $\Aut$ maps an algebra $A$ to its automorphism group.
2. We fix some algebra $R$ and define a functor $\Aut_R,$ where $\Aut_R(A)$ maps an algebra to the automorphism group of the tensor product $R \otimes A.$ From this, we construct a functor $\Aut$ which maps an algebra to the functor $\Aut_R.$ Then the goal is to prove $\Lie(\Aut(R)) = \Der(R).$

Does the first case suffice? I cannot see why the latter would be chosen, however it is used in [Zhihau Chang's notes on Lie algebras of affine group schemes](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~zhchang/Research/LieAlgGrpSch.pdf) (see Section 4.3) and 
[J.S. Milne's Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf) (see Ch VIII Section 2 and Ch XI).

In the second case I am struggling to understand how the morphism $\Aut_R(f)$ is defined, where $f : A \to B$ is an algebra morphism. Take $\alpha$ to be an automorphism on $R \otimes A,$ that is $\alpha \in \Aut_R(A).$ Then its image under $\Aut_R(f)$ is defined as the automorphism $\beta$ on $R \otimes B$ where
$$ \beta(r \otimes 1_B) = (1_R \otimes f)\alpha(r \otimes 1_A).$$
Why does it suffice to define $\beta$ on elements $r \otimes 1_B$? Moreover, how is it surjective on $R \otimes B$ if $f$ is not necessarily surjective?

Comment: Your first option is not functorial: An algebra homomorphism $A \to B$ does not give rise to a homomorphism between their automorphism groups.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Is there any intuition behind using the tensor product?

Comment: Yes, because the idea is not "automorphisms of the input", but "automorphisms of $R$ with coefficients in the input". Actually, it should be $\mathbf{Aut}_R$, not $\mathbf{Aut}$, and your parentheses in "\Lie(\Aut)(R)" are misplaced.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have altered the second part of my question to be more clear (I hope). Do you have any insights? Perhaps you could submit as an answer. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: The way you defined $\mathbf{Aut}$, it is not a functor from algebras to groups, but rather a functor from algebras to (affine) algebraic groups. You seem to be getting confused by the two arguments (you can and should curry one of them depending on what you want to do, but keep in mind which is which!).

Comment: @darijgrinberg $\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathbf{Aut}}$ Is the following correct? $\Aut$ maps an algebra $R$ to $\Aut_R,$ an algebraic group. But $\Aut_R$ can also be considered as a functor from algebras to groups. My issue is then understanding how the functor $\Aut_R$ maps morphisms. I have updated the notation again in the question to better reflect your comments

Comment: So you have an algebra morphism $f : A \to B$, and you want to define a group morphism $\mathbf{Aut}_R \left(f\right) : \mathbf{Aut}_R \left(A\right) \to \mathbf{Aut}_R \left(B\right)$, that is, a group morphism $\mathbf{Aut}_R \left(f\right) : \operatorname{Aut}_A\left(R \otimes A\right) \to \operatorname{Aut}_B\left(R \otimes B\right)$. That latter morphism should map each $A$-module (or $A$-algebra? your choice, but make that choice) automorphism $\phi$ of $R \otimes A$ to a $B$-module automorphism $\phi'$ of $R \otimes B$. It remains to define ...

Comment: ... this $\phi'$. Here is how to do this: Tensoring the $A$-module $R \otimes A$ with the $A$-$B$-bimodule $B$ (which is an $A$-module thanks to the algebra morphism $f : A \to B$), we obtain a $B$-module $\left(R \otimes A\right) \otimes_A B \cong R \otimes B$. But the automorphism $\phi$ of $R \otimes A$ gives rise to an automorphism $\phi \otimes_A \operatorname{id}_B$ of $\left(R \otimes A\right) \otimes_A B$. Since $\left(R \otimes A\right) \otimes_A B \cong R \otimes B$, we can reinterpret this as a $B$-module automorphism of $R \otimes B$; this will be our $\phi'$.